# Swift: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier in tables with sections

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

In my iOS app I have a table with 4 sections. I created a subtitle cell for each section and each cell has got its own identifier as you can see from the screenshot:

[image]

The problem is that when I need to insert a cell in that section by creating it with its identifier, I get am exception saying 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ... ' 
Here's my method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?
        var selectedStatus:String

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OpenTasks",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedStatus = "Aperti"
            break
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClosedTasks",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedStatus = "Chiusi"
            break
        case 2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExpiredTasks",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedStatus = "Scaduti"
            break
        case 3:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SuspendedTasks",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedStatus = "Sospesi"
            break
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedStatus = ""
            break

        }

        let task = self.organizedTasks.items[selectedStatus]![indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = task.titolo
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = task.priorita
        return cell!

}
```

I don't know what I am missing...
Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making mistake in you code by using `let` to every `cell` variable.

This is right way to do it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?
    var selectedStatus:String

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OpenTasks",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        selectedStatus = "Aperti"
        break
    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClosedTasks",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        selectedStatus = "Chiusi"
        break
    case 2:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExpiredTasks",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        selectedStatus = "Scaduti"
        break
    case 3:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SuspendedTasks",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        selectedStatus = "Sospesi"
        break
    default:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        selectedStatus = ""
        break

    }

    let task = self.organizedTasks.items[selectedStatus]![indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = task.titolo
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = task.priorita
    return cell!
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, This looks like a disaster of an approach to using a tableview. 
Secondly, your first identifier in the screenshot is OpenTask (singular), but your code is looking for OpenTasks (plural).

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I have corrected it...but the problems seems to be the fact that I had set the table view as Static Cells because it was the only option where I saw the menu "Sections"...I don't know why it doesn't work with that.

Comment: Secondly, why is this a disaster? What have I done so wrong? I only followed a tutorial... :(

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial, I dont see how this approach can be beneficial. Are you having a different design for each Cell? The reason I ask is because I assume from your code that there is maybe a different screen being loaded depending on selectedStatus? If you could provide some information on what your trying to achieve then I could elaborate more

Comment: this is the tutorial I had found: http://makeapppie.com/2015/02/17/swift-swift-tutorials-introducing-table-views/

Comment: Anyway I switched my table tipe to static cell and it works now but I am afraid I need the dynamic prototype otherwise maybe the search ball won't work, will it?

Comment: You have a searchbar on a static table?

Comment: So, I am meeting different problems and actually I don't know how to go on: if I set the table view as static cell then the table is not created and an exception is raised saying that it cannot dequeue a cell whose identifier is Cell...this is strange, because in the builder interface that identifier is set.

Comment: otherwise, if I set the table view as dynamic then the tables and cells are correctly loaded but when I start typing in the search bar, then the same exception is raised... :(

Comment: Dynamic cells is the correct approach. I cant tell you why its crashing without seeing the code. Im assuming you want all the cells to look the same right? Just with different data?

Comment: if you want the code is here http://pastebin.com/dUQdaK7b I think the problem is because I have a table with sections and maybe they can't be used together the search bar right?

Comment: anyway yes, all the cells are the same but only the content changes

Comment: Ok, I see now. Also Ive seen your new post regarding your intentions with the search bar so we can continue on there.

Comment: ok thank you, so I'll wait your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440718/swift-ios-8-can-a-table-with-sections-have-a-search-bar